# Azure App insights Adaptive Sampling includedTypes not working

Tags: azure-application-insights, sampling, telemetry

I want to sample apply Adaptive Sampling only to "Dependency" itemType. I used the below code to achieve this,

```
builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond: 250, includedTypes: "Dependency");
```

But the problem is the Adaptive Sampling is being applied to all the itemTypes instead of just sampling only "Dependency". Did anyone face the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As per the method `UseAdaptiveSampling` definition:

[image]

So you can use it as below:

```
 builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond: 250, includedTypes: "Dependency", excludedTypes: "Event;Exception;PageView;Request;Trace");
```

---

**Original answer:**

Please take a look at [Configure sampling settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configure-sampling-settings) -> **Important** section as below:

**If you use this method to configure sampling, please make sure to set the aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling property to false when calling AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry().**

So change your code like below:

```
    //other code

    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:250, includedTypes: "Dependency");

    //add the following code
    var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
    aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

    //other code
```

Comment: Does disabling AdaptiveSampling after doing this builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:250, includedTypes: "Dependency");, will not disable AdaptiveSampling completely?

Comment: @VenkataAnusha, this should work as per the doc. And also, I find a more direct solution, please see the updated answer.

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned above, it is disabling the sampling all together. Even dependecy is not being sampled.

Comment: and are you using asp.net core web app? and let me know the version of .net core as well as the nuget version of application insights.

Comment: and one more thing I should mention, if the data volume is not very large, it will not be sampled. But the thing confused me is that they provide maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond in sdk, so I need to confirm this from MS support.

Comment: These are the versions I am using,
ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Nuget Package manager 4.6.0

And the data volume is reaching Threshold, so that should be fine. 


This code you mentioned above, after setting includeTypes, setting EnableAdaptivesampling to False.

Comment: @VenkataAnusha,a quick update, I did reach out to the support team, but no feedback till now:(.

Comment: Old thread, but since the conversation above is confusing, I came to say that this answer is the way to go.